# how to send an approval in one flow and getting response in another flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow, power-automate, approval-process

I have a scenario like I have to send approval of 30 documents at a time, but in my case I am sending an approval and waiting for that response to send an approval email for next document.

So second approval mail will send after the first approval get response and so on

Is there any way to send all the approvals in a single shot and wait for response later for each document in another flow

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please following steps:**

1. You can add a column in the specified list to store Approval ID.

[image]

2. The First Approval Flow:

[image]

3. The Second Approval Flow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Use [Create an approval](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/approvals/#create-an-approval) action in your first flow to start approval process. This action does not wait for the approval to complete.
2. Store the Approval ID somewhere in SharePoint list.
3. Use [Wait for an approval](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/approvals/#wait-for-an-approval) action in your 2nd flow. This action waits for a specified approval to complete.
   This action also requires "Approval ID". You can use the approval ID saved in above step here.